# Pure JavaScript replacement for :hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

My goal, essentially, is to have the CSS :hover replaced by JavaScript. The reason is that I need a loop to be executed on a variable number of divs that will be nested inside the parent div that should react upon :hover.

The problem, however, is that I have no idea how to target just the div being hovered over without hard-coding in specific IDs - something that I will not be able to do once applied to my project, a tumblr theme.

**HTML**

```
<div id="motherbox">
    <div class="middlebox">
        <div class="childbox">One</div>
        <div class="childbox">Two</div>
        <div class="childbox">Three</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="motherbox">
    <div class="middlebox">
        <div class="childbox">One</div>
        <div class="childbox">Two</div>
        <div class="childbox">Three</div>
        <div class="childbox">Four</div>
        <div class="childbox">Five</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#motherbox {
    width:30%;
    height:100px;
    margin:100px auto;
    background-color:gray;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById("motherbox").onmouseenter = function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
};

document.getElementById("motherbox").onmouseleave = function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
};
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaikid/6pgvd94v/2/)

My question is - how do I cause divs with the same class or id to react individually (or, rather, not all at once) on hover using javascript, rather than CSS?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @zzzzBov edited to add clarification to the question at hand - sorry about that!

Comment: why are you attaching hover to the `#motherbox` element when you really want the hover to affect the `.childbox` elements? Select those elements instead.

Comment: @zzzzBov my goal is to have the .childbox elements react when the #motherbox element is being hovered over - I explained this poorly in my question. My main concern is just to have the #motherbox elements react individually upon hover, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can select elements having a particular class using `getElementsByClassName`.

Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sachinnambiar/avr92623/).

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('childbox');
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) { 
  elements[i].onmouseleave = function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
};
}
```

Comment: this aint even close to hover

Comment: This works fantastically - I modified it a bit and I believe it will suit my needs perfectly. My question is - how does this work? My understanding is that it loops through all the divs and "readies" them - then, when activated, they proceed with the function. Is this correct, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @knitevision: Sachin's answer sure looks like it fits the question to me. What's the problem with it (other than creating more functions than needed)?

Comment: @KaiAragaki Yes, you are correct, it is just appending ommouseleave event on all the div's with given classname.

Answer (score 0):

So use instead of getElementById this:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

And provide classess for your divs, where you want have that event.