# Javascript has methods to simulate user interactions like .click(), .focus(), .blur(). But no .hover(). Can JS simulate a hover / mouseover?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-driven, event-driven-design

Javascript enables user interactions to be simulated.

Any script can simulate a user interaction like `click` or `focus` on a specific element on the page, by using the methods `.click()` and `.focus()`.

**Example:**

```js
const square = document.getElementsByClassName('square')[0];

const clickSquare = () => {

  event.target.dataset.receivedAction = 'click';
  event.target.innerHTML = '<p>I\'ve been clicked!</p>';
}

const clearSquare = () => {

  square.removeAttribute('data-received-action');
  square.innerHTML = '';
}

square.addEventListener('click', clickSquare, false);

const clickButton = document.querySelector('[data-deliver-action="click"]');
const clearButton = document.querySelector('[data-deliver-action="clear"]');

clickButton.addEventListener('click', () => square.click(), false);
clearButton.addEventListener('click', clearSquare, false);
```

```css
.square {
display: block;
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
margin: 12px 6px;
text-align: center;
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 14px;
text-transform: uppercase;
overflow: hidden;
cursor: pointer;
}

button {
display: block;
width: 160px;
margin: 6px;
cursor: pointer;
}

.square {
color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.square[data-received-action="click"] {
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="square" tabindex="0"></div>

<button type="button" data-deliver-action="click">Click the Square</button>
<button type="button" data-deliver-action="clear">Clear Square</button>
```

The square above listens for a `click event`. We can either click on the square directly or we can press the **Click the Square** button which then clicks on the square itself via the `.click()` method.

Either action results in the square receiving a `click` event.

But this is only possible because the `.click()` method exists.

A `.hover()` (or even `.mouseover()`) method would also be useful, but it doesn't exist.

Is it possible to computationally simulate a hover (or a mouseover) in the absence of these methods?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Pure JavaScript replacement for :hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31629021/pure-javascript-replacement-for-hover)

Comment: @GeorgeJempty That has nothing to do with what is being asked here.

Comment: Trust me then, there's a duplicate out there somewhere, at least I'm effing looking for one

Comment: @GeorgeJempty How about the awesome answer below?

Comment: You can of course fire event `mouseover` listeners using `dispatchEvent`, but it's not possible to simulate a real, user-induced hover.

Comment: The question above is not a duplicate of the question referenced in the duplicate notice. The latter question is concerned with CSS pseudo-class `:hover` - this question is concerned with computationally simulating human user interaction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears not to be widely documented across the web, but it ***is*** possible to computationally simulate a human moving a mouse pointer over an element in the same way that `element.click()` simulates a human clicking on an element.

The correct approach is to use:

```
eventTarget.dispatchEvent(event)
```

in *combination* with a JS-native `event`.

Most references to `dispatchEvent()` involve a custom-written event, but, to reiterate, it *is* possible to use a **JS-native** `event` - in this case `mouseover`.

So... instead of the following, utilising the `.click()` method:

```
clickButton.addEventListener('click', () => square.click(), false);
```

We can deploy:

```
clickButton.addEventListener('click', () => {

  let hover = new Event('mouseover');
  square.dispatchEvent(hover);

}, false);
```

**Working Example:**

```js
const square = document.getElementsByClassName('square')[0];

const clickSquare = () => {

  event.target.dataset.receivedAction = 'click';
  event.target.innerHTML = '<p>I\'ve been clicked!</p>';
}

const hoverSquare = () => {

  event.target.dataset.receivedAction = 'hover';
  event.target.innerHTML = '<p>I\'ve been hovered over!</p>';
}

const clearSquare = () => {

  square.removeAttribute('data-received-action');
  square.innerHTML = '';
}

square.addEventListener('mouseover', hoverSquare, false);
square.addEventListener('click', clickSquare, false);

const clickButton = document.querySelector('[data-deliver-action="click"]');
const hoverButton = document.querySelector('[data-deliver-action="hover"]');
const clearButton = document.querySelector('[data-deliver-action="clear"]');

clickButton.addEventListener('click', () => square.click(), false);

hoverButton.addEventListener('click', () => {

  let hover = new Event('mouseover');
  square.dispatchEvent(hover);

}, false);

clearButton.addEventListener('click', clearSquare, false);
```

```css
.square {
display: block;
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
margin: 12px 6px;
text-align: center;
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 14px;
text-transform: uppercase;
overflow: hidden;
cursor: pointer;
}

button {
display: block;
width: 160px;
margin: 6px;
cursor: pointer;
}

.square {
color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.square[data-received-action="click"] {
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}

.square[data-received-action="hover"] {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: rgb(255, 125, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="square" tabindex="0"></div>

<button type="button" data-deliver-action="click">Click the Square</button>
<button type="button" data-deliver-action="hover">Hover over the Square</button>
<button type="button" data-deliver-action="clear">Clear Square</button>
```

Comment: This answer conflates two non alike things: `onmouseover != :hover`. It isn't simulating anything, it's just doing a normal thing.

Comment: This question is nothing to  do with CSS. It isn't about `:hover`. I am addressing how javascript can simulate a human user *positioning* a mouse pointer over an element in the same way that `.click()` simulates a human user clicking on an element.

Comment: Is my use of the verb **hover** confusing you with the CSS pseudo-class `:hover`? If so, I am happy to update the verb to another like **pointer-touch**.

Comment: I'm not confusing this with CSS. You can leave CSS and `:hover` out of it. The same problem still applies, you are conflating `.hover()` with `.onmouseover()`, one of which can be triggered manually, one that cannot. This isn't simulating anything, it's just doing the one of those two things that can be done at all.

Comment: First you write: _"This answer conflates two non alike things: `onmouseover != :hover`"_. Then, when I responded _"This question is nothing to do with CSS"_, you write _"You can leave CSS and `:hover` out of it"_. Which `:hover` were you referring to the first time around, if not the CSS `:hover`?

Comment: Re: _"This isn't simulating anything."_ We can all see that it is. Just as `element.click()` computationally simulates a human clicking on an element, this method computationally simulates a human positioning a pointer over an element.

Comment: Connecting A→C and B→C so that either trigger method causes the same function to run is not the same as A triggering B. That distinction (and the fact that there are good reasons _not_ to be able to trigger B by anything but an actual B) is being papered over in this answer at, I think, the expense of people having a clear understanding of the actual constraints they are working under.

Comment: Do you value methods like `.click()`, `.focus()` and `.blur()`? If you do, then you surely see merit in a `.pointertouch()` method? I would contend that there is great utility in being able to execute mouse actions computationally which are normally user-executed. I'm not sure if you agree with this or not.